# Format Text in Oracle using regular expression

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, full-text-search

I want to format data in a particular column (varchar) using regular expressions.

The requirement is that any prefix "SAINT"or "ST."or "STE" should be replaced with "ST". All special characters like "'" , "-" etc.. should be removed, and any suffix "COUNTY"/ "CITY" should be removed.

For example, the text **ST. JOHN'S CITY** should be formatted as ***ST JOHNS***
or the text **STE ABC-STE'XYZ CITY COUNTY COUNTY** should be formatted as ***ST ABCSTEXYZ CITY COUNTY***.

Can anyone plz help..

Thanks

Comment: This clearly follows from your previous question. It seems you are slowly on your way to hand-rolling **Oracle Text**. This library provides full-text searching with fuzzy matching: you should definitely check out Name Search. In the context of this question you might be interested in its Thesaurus feature. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24435/toc.htm).

Comment: Is your question specifically about the [`regexp_replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions149.htm) function? If so what aspect of it do you need help with? If the question is actually how to apply multiple standard transformations to a text column then please update it to make that clearer.

Comment: I've edited it.

Comment: Are you sure about the requirement? I live in a locality called UNIVERSITY CITY. The city is referred to as "city of University City". The name is two words; "City" in this context is not a suffix. Removing it will result in a city name that is not recognized by the post office. Is that result the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if following works for you. I tested it and it gave correct results .

```
create table test_stack (id number , address varchar2(4000)) ;

insert into test_stack values( 1 , 'ST. JOHN''S CITY') ;
insert into test_stack values( 2 , 'STE JOHN-ABC-/''DEF CITY COUNTY CITY') ;

select id , 
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace( address , '^(\S*)' , 'ST') , '(\S*)$' , '') , '([^[:blank:]a-zA-Z\d])' , ''  ) 
from test_stack
```